# MS Access - How to tell which table/query expression builder fetches its results from

Tags: forms, ms-access, expression

I am new to MS Access and have taken over a project that was very poorly designed.

In access, they created a form that uses the expression builder to display data in a text box on the form.

the expression builder window is below

```
=[BaseCst]-[SavingPFP]-[FullVehSaving]-[sscost]
```

What I cant figure out, is which table or query the expression is fetching data from as the expression is unique tot he form? how can I easily work out which tables the data is being derived from so as to trace the application logic?

Thanks for the help and apologies for the 'non logic' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you are in `Design Mode` in your form click on show the `Property Sheet`.
- Click on the grey background of your form (to select the form itself and no specific object on the form)
- On the `Data` tab look at the Record Source.

This is where those names are coming from. They should be named uniquely which is why they didn't require any additional qualification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need construction like this: [table1].[field1]

Comment: Thanks, if construction is already done and I am trying to understand what is happening, how do I deduce where query is coming from? Thanks for your time